# How to Swap on Jupiter in Python

Tags: python, jupiter

I am trying to build a bot to swap programmatically in python on Jupiter, but could not find any doc for that. Anyone managed to do so please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this API: https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/swap-api to fetching prices and generate the transactions needed.

Along with the solana web3 library for signing and sending transactions.

Comment: Yes, that's what i am trying to replicate, but I'm stuck at point 6. Get the serialized transactions to perform the swap. I get {'error': 'Parse error: WrongSize at line 1 column 250'}. Maybe, my userPublicKey or destinationTokenAccount are not right. They are Pubkey.from_string('xxx').to_json() and Keypair.from_base58_string('xxx').to_json(). with from solders.pubkey import Pubkey and from solders.keypair import Keypair
. Is that correct?

Comment: You get this error from Jupiter or when signing your transaction? You should pass in Strings to the HTTP request. Can you paste a code snippet

Comment: from the requests to jupiter, not the transaction

Comment: Yeah, you should not be converting it to json, leave it as a string.